# Increase Async HttpClient GetStringAsync speed. Won't make any check difference if I pass different values to check at the same time

Tags: c#, task, httpclient

I'm currently checking on my own server if a username turns aviable or not. This code will be run in a while loop until the condition turns true and some other code will be executed.

**My problem:**

It doesn't matter which value I would store inside the `int amount` parameter. The speed of the checks would remain the same.

Could this be caused by some `DefaultConnectionLimit` or something similare?

**What I currently want to do:**

I want to increase the following value:

```
int amount = Int32.Parse(bunifuCustomLabel11.Text);
```

to run more checks at the same time. But at some specific point the speed wouldn't increase anymore. So let's say I would pass the value 100 then the code would be executed in the same speed as when I entered 200 for example.

**Functions:** Which check the current status of the handle/username and return true or false:

```
private async Task CheckUntilOneOfTheUsersIsAvaliable()
{
    int amount = Int32.Parse(bunifuCustomLabel11.Text);
    await Task.WhenAny(Enumerable.Range(0, amount).Select(i => CheckUntilUserIsAvaliable()));

    // If aviable run some other code..
}

private async Task CheckUntilUserIsAvaliable()
{
    while (!await IsUserAvaliable(bunifuMetroTextbox3.Text) && changedUser == false)
    {
        // method_5 increaes a label
        method_5();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

private async Task<bool> IsUserAvaliable(string handle)
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://urlcom/script.php?user=" + handle);
                return content.Contains("No users found");
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating and disposing too many instances of HttpClient can have that effect. Create one instance and reuse that for the life of the application. Also that logic with the infinite loop is only going to cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations to

1. The number of tasks that can run in parallel. Certainly not 100, or even 200.
2. The number of connections the service or the hosted server allows from the same client.

You can write some debug log to see how many `HttpClient` instances are actively talking to server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have a look at my Webserver. If I check the responses in fiddler then there's way less requests actually.